# Kibana discover: search for special character: '@'

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, kibana-4

I want to display all entries of an elasticsearch database with kibana, that contain the special character @. To be more specific, I search for that in the field friendly_name.

I have tried the following:

```
*@
*\@
*"\@"*
friendly_name:*@
friendly_name:*\@
friendly_name:*"\@"*
```

Neither one of those worked, I also found pages like:
https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters

which tell to escape special characters with '\', which does not work here, apparently.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch searching with hyphen inside a word](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301849/elasticsearch-searching-with-hyphen-inside-a-word)

Comment: Kibana uses `query_string` behind the scene, thus why marking this as a duplicate. Matching `-` or `@` is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As per Apache Lucene documentation of query syntax @ is not a part of special characters group, therefore we cannot search for @ in Kibana as well.

Special characters allowed are:-

> Special characters: + – & || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ ” ~ * ? : \

Comment: This does not at all?

Answer (score 0):

I would give the following a try:

```
friendly_name:"@"
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried it too. Doesn't work. I wanted to put that as a comment but didn't have enough reputation so had to put as an answer!! :/