# How to search for "T-shirt" in attribute

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-7

I don't get results from the category.name = "T-shirts & Sweaters" whenever I try to search on "T-shirt"

This is an example query:

```
{
    "explain": true,
    "size": 3,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "visibility": [
                                    3,
                                    4
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "status": [
                                    0,
                                    1
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "stock.is_in_stock": [
                                    true
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "must": {
                "function_score": {
                    "functions": [
                        {
                            "filter": {
                                "match": {
                                    "attribute_code": "attribute_value"
                                }
                            },
                            "weight": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "score_mode": "multiply",
                    "boost_mode": "multiply",
                    "max_boost": 100,
                    "min_score": 1,
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "multi_match": {
                                        "fields": [
                                            "name^2",
                                            "sku^50",
                                            "category.name^1"
                                        ],
                                        "query": "T-shirt",
                                        "operator": "or",
                                        "fuzziness": 2,
                                        "cutoff_frequency": 0.01,
                                        "max_expansions": 3,
                                        "prefix_length": 2,
                                        "minimum_should_match": "75%",
                                        "tie_breaker": "1"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "should": [
                                            {
                                                "terms": {
                                                    "configurable_children.sku": [
                                                        "T", "shirt"
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "match_phrase": {
                                                    "sku": {
                                                        "query": "T-shirt",
                                                        "boost": 1
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "match_phrase": {
                                                    "configurable_children.sku": {
                                                        "query": "T-shirt",
                                                        "boost": 1
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get results but only with the letter "T" in the product name. So it looks like T-shirt is split up in 2 search terms "T" and "shirt".

(Part of) response:

```
{
    "took": 15,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 11,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 14.911253,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_score": 14.911253,
                "_source": {
                    ...
                    "name": "VICTORINOX 0.6463.T",
                    "url_path": "victorinox-0-6463-t",
                    "category": [
                        {
                            "category_id": 412,
                            "name": "Pocket Knives",
                            "position": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    ...
                },
                "_explanation": {
                    "value": 14.911253,
                    "description": "sum of:",
                    "details": [
                        {
                            "value": 14.911253,
                            "description": "function score, product of:",
                            "details": [
                                {
                                    "value": 14.911253,
                                    "description": "sum of:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "value": 14.911253,
                                            "description": "sum of:",
                                            "details": [
                                                {
                                                    "value": 14.911253,
                                                    "description": "weight(name:t in 1592) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:",
                                                    "details": [
                                                        {
                                                            "value": 14.911253,
                                                            "description": "score(freq=1.0), computed as boost * idf * tf from:",
                                                            "details": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "value": 4.4,
                                                                    "description": "boost",
                                                                    "details": []
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "value": 6.521112,
                                                                    "description": "idf, computed as log(1 + (N - n + 0.5) / (n + 0.5)) from:",
                                                                    "details": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "value": 19,
                                                                            "description": "n, number of documents containing term",
                                                                            "details": []
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "value": 13246,
                                                                            "description": "N, total number of documents with field",
                                                                            "details": []
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "value": 0.51968455,
                                                                    "description": "tf, computed as freq / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * dl / avgdl)) from:",
                                                                    "details": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "value": 1.0,
                                                                            "description": "freq, occurrences of term within document",
                                                                            "details": []
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "value": 1.2,
                                                                            "description": "k1, term saturation parameter",
                                                                            "details": []
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "value": 0.75,
                                                                            "description": "b, length normalization parameter",
                                                                            "details": []
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "value": 3.0,
                                                                            "description": "dl, length of field",
                                                                            "details": []
                                                                        },
                                                                        {
                                                                            "value": 4.32523,
                                                                            "description": "avgdl, average length of field",
                                                                            "details": []
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": 1.0,
                                    "description": "min of:",
                                    "details": [
                                        {
                                            "value": 1.0,
                                            "description": "No function matched",
                                            "details": []
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "value": 100.0,
                                            "description": "maxBoost",
                                            "details": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
```

If I remove the sku and name part from the multi match terms I get no results at all, however I do have a lot of products in the category.name = "T-shirts & Sweaters".

How can I make sure these will popup first?
What do I need to change in my settings?

Comment: Looks like your question is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301849/elasticsearch-searching-with-hyphen-inside-a-word

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ElasticSearch searching with hyphen inside a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31301849/elasticsearch-searching-with-hyphen-inside-a-word)