Elasticsearch custom tokenizer
In my business, we operate a lot on codes with the format "rtu-2004-t89". This code always starts with "rtu" and then has various combinations of letters and numbers. These codes are very often found in the content that we index into elasticsearch.
Unfortunately, during indexing, the tokenizer breaks these codes into separate words using the dash character as a separator.
For this reason, when the user wants to search for this code, they do not get the correct result.
How can you write your own tokenizer so that it does not break these codes into separate tokens?

Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/q/31301849/2745495?

You just use the keyword which uses a whitespace tokenizer from the default elastic search. Don't forget to add lowercase normalizer to make easier user to search using lowercase.
for the example :
Here the mapping
"sku": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
          }
        }
      }

You must add normalizer in your index's setting like this :
"normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "type": "custom"
        }
      }

After u set the settings and mapping. The query should be like this, for the example I use match. You can change whatever u want :
 "match": {
              "sku.keyword": {
                "query": "rtu-2024..."
              }
            }


You misunderstood me a bit. The codes in the format I gave are not assigned to a single field that contains only this code, but are in the content in several fields. For example "Lorem ipsum dolor rtu-2004-t89 sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod"

Using keyword can work, but prevents doing full-text searches.

Use custom word delimiter and set preserve_original true. set another configuration like split etc just ajust like what u need.
